# Group other data based on interval class

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe :

| Age | Customer.Type | Type.Of.TRavel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | First-Time | Bussiness |
| 25 | Returning | Personal |
| 40 | First-Time | Personal |
| 35 | Returning | Bussiness |
| 45 | Returning | Bussiness |
| 28 | First-Time | Personal |
| 39 | Returning | Bussiness |

then I make the age column into an interval class :

```
interval.age <- [20,24) [24,28) [28,32) [32,36) [36,40) [40,44)
```

How can I group the number of categories `Customer.Type` and `Type.Of.TRAvel` by age class interval?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(age = c(20, 25, 40, 35, 45, 28, 39),
                 customer_type=factor(c(1,2,1,2,2,1,2)),
                 travel_type=factor(c(1,2,2,1,1,2,1)))

levels(df$customer_type) <- c("first-time", "returning")
levels(df$travel_type) <- c("business", "personal")
                 

df$interval_age <- cut(df$age, 
                       breaks=c(20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, Inf),
                       right=FALSE)


library(tidyr)
df %>% group_by(customer_type, travel_type, interval_age) %>% tally

# A tibble: 7 × 4
# Groups:   customer_type, travel_type [4]
  customer_type travel_type interval_age     n
  <fct>         <fct>       <fct>        <int>
1 first-time    business    [20,24)          1
2 first-time    personal    [28,32)          1
3 first-time    personal    [40,44)          1
4 returning     business    [32,36)          1
5 returning     business    [36,40)          1
6 returning     business    [44,Inf)         1
7 returning     personal    [24,28)          1
```